# When I try to install or remove app, I get "cannot communicate with server" error

Tags: command-line, software-installation, snap

Everytime I try to install or remove app with "sudo snap remove" or "sudo snap install" command, I get the following error: "error: cannot communicate with server: timeout exceeded while waiting for response".

I've seen advise to run "systemctl start snapd.service" command, but it doesn't work as well: "Job for snapd.service failed because a timeout was exceeded".

P.S. Everything is ok with the internet connection on the Virtual Machine.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it depended on the network connection. It worked in the office, but not at home, where I had to change to another provider to get it working.
(Seems like snap has  its own routines for the communication, which is pretty bad.)